# max() in mysql returns 9999

Tags: mysql, max

i have a database table with unique column containing value like

```
invid
----------
500
1000
B2222
A9998
A9999
A10000
```

the problem whenever my query max(invid) is return A9999 what is the solution

Comment: Because of lexicographical ordering.

Comment: Please review the answers given below, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT CONCAT('A', MAX(0+SUBSTRING(invid,2))) FROM your_table
```

The problem is you're trying to find the max value of the alphanumeric, in this case A9999 is greater than A10000, it's not the same with 9999 and 10000.

Comment: A not a default value

Answer (score 0):

You can `SELECT` the maximum of the numerical value in the `invid` column:

```
SELECT t.invid, MAX(t.value) AS maxValue
FROM
(
    SELECT invid,
        CASE WHEN invid LIKE '[A-Z]%'
            THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(invid, 2) AS UNSIGNED)
            ELSE CAST(invid AS UNSIGNED)
        END AS value
    FROM yourTable
) t
```

This assumes that each entry in `invid` will have at most one letter prefixing the number.  This does not take into account the possibility of ties for maximum value.

Comment: where is the table name??

Comment: Sorry I am on a phone at the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99692/discussion-between-faztrick-fazil-pv-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: I cannot use the chat feature as I am using a phone now.

Comment: sorry bro :( same i going to another way

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to correct the problem permanently by changing the column to an auto_increment and remove the `A` letter.

Otherwise you could use following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('A'
         , MAX(0+SUBSTRING(invid,2))) 
FROM table
```